# write list of all the files in a directory and subdirectory except 1 in linux

Tags: bash, find, ls

Suppose I have 2 directories `src/A`, `src/B` and `src/C`.

I want to list all the files inside A and B but not C.

This working fine but it's also listing file of `src/C`

```
find src/ -type f >> changed-files-list.txt
```

I tried

```
find src/ -type f -not -name 'src/C' >> changed-files-list.txt
```

but it's not working I guess because I used -type f. How can exclude a directory from above command?

Comment: `find src/A src/B -type f >> changed-files-list.txt`

Comment: @Fravadona In real scenario I have a lot of directories but want to exclude only one. So I was looking for a way to exclude a directory solution instead of including all directories but thanks for the help

Comment: The `-path` option is a little tricky to use but it can serve this purpose: `find src -type f -not -path 'src/C/*' >> changed-files-list.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
shopt -s extglob dotglob
find src/!(C) -type f >> changed-files-list.txt
```

- The `extglob` option with `shopt -s` turns on Bash *extended globbing*.  See [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).  It causes `src/!(C)` to expand to the same list as `src/*`, but excluding `src/C`.
- The `dotglob` option with `shopt -s` causes glob patterns to match files or directories whose names start with a dot (`.`).  It means that `src/!(C)` will match `src/.D`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to use `ls` command

```
ls -1 src/{A,B}/*
```

Option `-1` list one file per line (like find).

Advantage list only the specified directories. And not traversing under.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-prune` to omit the directory:

```
find src -path src/C -prune -o \( -type f  -print \)
```

If you are willing to accept the line of output that includes C itself (but none of the files in C), you can simplify that to:

```
find src -name C -prune -o -type f
```

(this will also omit any files names `C`)